# Limit of a function vs sequence as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\cos (\frac{\pi }{2}+\pi n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

I know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\cos (\frac{\pi }{2}+\pi n)$ does not exist. However, I am not sure about the sequence
$(n\cos (\frac{\pi }{2}+\pi n))_{n=1}^\infty$. By evaluating this sequence, I get indeterminate form $\infty\cdot0$. Intuitevly, I believe that the answer is $0$, because $0$ can be treated as a solid (?). For instance, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\cdot0=0$. So, how can I interpret these results?

Comment: The first limit is indeterminate according to WolframAlpha. And yes, I want to know if  there is a difference if n is real vs an integer.

Comment: ok. I see, yes, if n is taken to be real, the limit does not exist. if n is taken to be an integer the limit exists and is zero.

Comment: Michelle's answer explains why the limit is 0 for the integer case (ie: the sequence case).

Comment: In the integer case, $\sin(n\pi)$ is always zero. But in the real case $\sin(n\pi)$ can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
n \cos(n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2})=n(\cos(n\pi)\cos(\frac \pi 2) -\sin(n\pi)\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}))=0\to0.
$$